# Create a new workspace in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I don't see any menu item I can use to create a new workspace.

What should I use to create a new workspace and move some of the projects from existing default workspace to a new workspace?

I am using Windows with Eclipse 3.7.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

I use File -> Switch Workspace -> Other... and type in my new workspace name.

[image: New workspace composite screenshot] (EDIT: Added the composite screen shot.)

Once in the new workspace, File -> Import... and under General choose "Existing Projects into Workspace. Press the Next button and then Browse for the old projects you would like to import. Check "Copy projects into workspace" to make a copy.

Comment: In addition to the answer from @rajah9, you may also want to copy settings, especially if you have good Working Sets defined.

Comment: Typing the name of a non-existent folder path does work ... but is surprising ... and surprising is not good UX. I assumed there was a create workspace menu item somewhere. Yet another weird aspect of Eclipse.

Answer (score 33):

In **Window->Preferences->General->Startup and Shutdown->Workspaces**, make sure that 'Prompt for Workspace on startup' is checked.

Then close eclipse and reopen.

Then you'll be prompted for a workspace to open.  You can create a new workspace from that dialogue.

Or File->Switch Workspace->Other...

Answer (score 16):

You can create multiple workspaces in Eclipse. You have to just specify the path of the workspace during Eclipse startup. You can even switch workspaces via File→Switch workspace.

You can then import project to your workspace, copy paste project to your new workspace folder, then

File→Import→Existing project in to workspace→select project.