# Mac OSX Android Developer Tools Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, nullpointerexception, adt

I have downloaded the ADT from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and when I follow the instructions for making a new project, on step 7 when I click "Finish", Eclipse gives me an error alert box, saying

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'Example'.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I get stuck at the New Project dialog because clicking Finish keeps giving the NPE. Even when I click cancel, try making a new project, exiting Eclipse, and trying again, it always gives the same error.

I have JDK 6 and JDK 7 installed. Using ADT Build: v22.6.2-1085508.

Here is a snippet of the Eclipse log file ([full log](http://pastebin.com/gys3RduU)):

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-06-11 22:40:51.991
!MESSAGE Failed to load properties file for project 'Example'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2014-06-11 22:40:51.993
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 75 2014-06-11 22:40:51.993
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'Example'.
!STACK 0

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.BaseBuilder.abortOnBadSetup(BaseBuilder.java:327)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.build(ResourceManagerBuilder.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a common bug on Maverics: [LINK](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68755). I've tried literally everything to fix it: reinstalling Eclipse and SDK, reinstalling Java, switching workspaces, performing updates in Eclipse and SDK Manager. I don't think there's anything we can do about it right now other than waiting for an update...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating new workspace or switching to another if you have one. Here is how you can change workspace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7234686/2741586.

If the problem persists, there might be serious problem in your ADT. Try updating SDK and Java in your MAC or downloading newer ADT.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I have already tried switching workspaces, with no luck. I believe I have the newest ADT, unless there is some beta package I can try..