# how to run luna eclipse and luna mars parallely...?

Tags: javafx, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna, eclipse-mars

Currently am working with two different projects in my company. One project runs on Eclipse luna IDE platform and another on Eclipse Mars IDE platform.

When ever i tried to open both the eclipse IDE together error will arise with respect to workspace, it will force me to close another IDE which am previously using.

I tried by creating different workspaces for both the IDE's but am unable to resolve this problem.

Is there any way to open both the eclipse IDE together without interruption.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have distinct workspaces for each eclipse session you want to keep open.

For how to achieve that, see e.g. [Create a new workspace in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234656/create-a-new-workspace-in-eclipse) .

Comment: Am working with linux platform not on windows. I want to establish both version of eclipse IDE together , not 2 projects in single IDE. Am facing issue even after creating different workspace for both the eclipse IDE

Comment: Linux or windows or foobar does not matter.  You need distinct workspaces.  I call mine /home/erwin/eclipseworkspace44 and /home/erwin/eclipseworkspace45 .

Comment: PS If you are experiencing problems getting something done and you want to be helped, then it might be useful to explain ***IN DETAIL*** what you tried and ***IN DETAIL*** what error responses you are getting.